# c#, vb, java, python script testing environment?

Tags: read-eval-print-loop

I was watching a video on KhanAcademy:
http://www.khanacademy.org/video/insertion-sort-in-python?playlist=Computer+Science

And i noticed the IDE he was using allowed a neat little interface for testing functions where you could code in however much you needed, then test it without the need to compile and run your entire application in order to test a function. Rather, in a command line, you could just say a = 100, then tell it to run a method on that value Function(a) and have it run.

I don't know how else to explain this other than telling you to watch that video. Now, I know in visual studio, you can run your application, then play with watched variables to manipulate the outcome, but thats not really the same. I'm looking for something quick and snappy out there similar to pyScripter in this sense. Does anyone know of any tools like this for any of aforementioned languages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For c# there is [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/). A c# scratch pad, that also speaks LINQ2SQL.
The concept in Python and similar languages is called [REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop), LINQPad is not exactly the same, it does not keep old results in the same way, you need to run complete snippets of code, but that usually is not a problem.

Comment: thank you. It helps to know what I'm looking for and what it's called (REPL). I looked up "c# repl" and i got http://www.mono-project.com/CsharpRepl. I have played with linqpad before, i will explore it more.

Comment: If you pay for LINQPad you get autocompletion and then it is pretty nice.